# Syntax Error with Double Quotes in an if Statement

Tags: python

Currently I'm making a login screen (without any graphics for rn, just the plain code) and this error continues to show up.

I have tried programs that run python and they all say that somewhere in the first line there is an invalid syntax. In VSC (what I'm using rn to code) it's underlining the second double quotes after the "s" in :Yes" and saying it's an invalid syntax() pylint(syntax-error)

```
if hasAccount not "Yes": #this line
       print("Would You Like to Create An Account?")
       createAccount = (input("Yes or No"))
         if createAccount not "Yes":
           print("Have a Nice Day!")
           exit
```

When I try to debug it doesn't let the code run, just citing invalid syntax

Comment: This appears to just be a typo. `hasAccount not "Yes"` should be `hasAccount != "Yes"`. Then the same with the similar line below it. The second `if` will cause the same error.

Comment: Was about to post what Carcigenicate said, but he beat me to it right as I finished writing my answer! C'est la vie, that's the answer. `variable1 not variable2` is not valid syntax. You usually want to use normal equality operators (`!=`, `==`, `>`, etc) rather than `is`, as `is` has a more specific meaning (`==` and `!=` test whether two variables are equal, whereas `is` and `is not` test whether two variables are the same; there is a subtle but important difference there!)

Comment: @Michael I've just voted to close this as a typo, as a generic syntax error seems unlikely to be able to help out anyone in the future.

Answer (score -2):

you're just missing an `is`.

`if hasAccount is not "Yes":` should work fine

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is a bad suggestion. `is` isn't guaranteed to be equivalent to `==` for Strings. `==` should be used instead.